# Using at&t iphone 5c in India

Tags: unlock, lte, iphone, att

Would an unlocked AT&T iphone 5c work well with 2G/3G in India? AFAIK, India doesn't have 4G yet. So, I am not too worried about 4G/LTE. Would it latch onto 3G in India? I bought the phone in USA.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you bought it in the USA.  I have the same phone, it works in the US with AT&T, Australia (Telstra), Europe (LeBara-France) and India (Orange), picking up 3G with no issues.

**Yes, your unlocked phone will work in India.**

Comment: Thanks Deesbek. Yes, I did buy it in the USA. Have you tried any other carrier other than orange in India?

Comment: No sorry, Orange only.